# jquery and setting range of values

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-select

I am trying to come up with a way using ajax and jquery to display a range of values for a select box.
The first drop down has options that need to talk to a 2nd drop box and that is a range of numbers, I know how to set the value of a drop down to 1 value, but not how set the whole range. By default the dropdowns are being generated by php range function.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
This is not the most elegant, but here is what i have

```
$('.change').change(function(){
var options='';
var max = $('.change option:selected').attr('title');
var min = $('.change option:selected').attr('id');


for(i=min; i <= max; i++){
    options+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
$('select[name=ticket_qty]').find("option").remove();

$('select[name=ticket_qty]').append(options);


});
```

I am having trouble pulling the "ID" and "TITLE" for the selected option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the list is large you might want to use something like:

```
var options='';
for(i=1; i <= 1234; i++){
    options+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
$(yourSelect).append(options);
```

Comment: How do pull the ID of a particular <option>

Comment: Do they have an ID and title set? Also, your example code implies that the id consists of an integer number, which is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If these are numerical values, you might want to look into using the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range). Otherwise, you'll just need to remove/add options in the select box by appending to the select tag.

On the change event of your first text box, call a function that will modify the options in select box 2, removing values that are no longer viable.

```
function addValue(value, target) {
  $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>').appendTo( target ); 
}

function clearValues (target) {
  $(target).find("option").remove();
}
```

You would then call the function as follows:

```
addValue(12,$("#select2 input") );
```

**Note: I haven't tested this code, it's just a general idea of an approach.**

Someting to that effect might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over the items in the select box (element.options) and then set the .selected property on a given property.

In that way you can set multiple selections.

ie. element.options[i].selected = true